# Storing the first value in a sequence and use the stored values where the condition meets

Tags: excel, vba

I have this table and the VBA code has to fetch Value from Product where the Primary value is Yes. But, Value has to be the First Value in the Sequence.

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| Product | Results | Primary |
+---------+---------+---------+
| A       |         |         |
| B       |         | Yes     |
| C       |         | Yes     |
| D       |         |         |
| E       |         | Yes     |
| F       |         |         |
| G       |         | Yes     |
| H       |         | Yes     |
| I       |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Expecting results:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| Product | Results | Primary |
+---------+---------+---------+
| A       |         |         |
| B       | A       | Yes     |
| C       | A       | Yes     |
| D       |         |         |
| E       | D       | Yes     |
| F       |         |         |
| G       | F       | Yes     |
| H       | F       | Yes     |
| I       |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

I have tried this below vba code, but doesn't work as i expected.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long

    lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To lr
        If Range("D" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
            Range("C" & i).Value = Range("B" & i - 1).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: is the `j` a typo? (and if you haven't been using `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules, you may want to start)

Comment: @Mistella yes. it is a typo.

Comment: @SJR  i am getting results, but it is pulling A, B but i want the First Value i.e. A to populate to all cells as long as there is Continuous Yes in the Primary Column.

Comment: @SJR yes.. You are correct. I am correcting it. Damn, so many errors in the questions. My Apologies.

Comment: No worries, you have an answer which I think is fine, pending my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming cols A B C use the below formula in B2

```
=If(C2="yes", if(B1="",A1,B1),"")
```

Copy this to all the linea below.

This will work as long as the first item is not primary.

U can even include this formula in vba and do the copy paste in vba

Comment: Good one, but I think the first B2 should be a B1 to avoid a circular reference?

Answer (score 1):

### Excel Formula

Here is an example of how your formula can look. This first looks to see if the primary field is "**Yes**". If so, then it checks if the previous result also was a yes, and grabs it's the result if so. Otherwise, it grabs the first value based on your example.

> =IF($C2="Yes", IF($C1="Yes", $B1, $A1),"")

*Adjust this as needed!*

---

### VBA Code

I would suggest creating a way of finding your headers, that way it is easier to update down the road in case it changes or there are more fields added. Below I added an example of what I would attempt to do.

I used a helper function (Inject) to build the actual formula and make it easier to read/debug if there are issues.

Feel free to add your own custom error handling as well.

> Just note this is one of many ways you could tackle this. I could even break this formula into even smaller components to abstract as much of it as possible.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub AddResultsToTable()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    'FIND COLUMN HEADERS TO USE IN FORMULA REFERENCES
    With Ws.UsedRange

        On Error GoTo Catch
        Dim Product As Range
        Set Product = .Find("Product")

        Dim Results As Range
        Set Results = .Find("Results")

        Dim Primary As Range
        Set Primary = .Find("Primary")

    End With

    'CREATE FORMULA. Example: =IF($C2="Yes", IF($C1="Yes", $B1, $A1),"")
    Dim CustomFormula As String
    CustomFormula = Inject("=IF(${0}='Yes', IF(${1}='Yes', ${2}, ${3}),'')", _
        Primary.Offset(1).Address(False, True), _
        Primary.Address(False, True), _
        Results.Address(False, True), _
        Product.Address(False, True) _
    )

    'SET FIRST RANGE EQUAL TO FORMULA & AUTOFILL FORMULA DOWN
    With Results.Offset(1)
        .Value = CustomFormula
        .AutoFill Range(.Address, Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, Product.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1))
    End With

Exit Sub
Catch:
    'You can do your error handling here.
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical

End Sub


'METHOD THAT ALLOWS A STRING TO BE REPLACED WITH VARIABLES AND SPECIAL CHARACTERS
Public Function Inject(ByVal Source As String, ParamArray Args() As Variant) As String

    '@AUTHOR: ROBERT TODAR
    '@EXAMPLE: Inject("${0}, ${1}!", "Hello", "Robert") --> Hello, Robert!

    'REPLACE SINGLE QUOTES WITH DOUBLE QUOTES
    Inject = Source
    Inject = Replace(Inject, "'", """")

    'REPLACE ${#} WITH VALUES STORED IN THE VALUE IN THAT INDEX.
    Dim Index As Integer
    For Index = LBound(Args, 1) To UBound(Args, 1)
        Inject = Replace(Inject, "${" & Index & "}", Args(Index), , , vbTextCompare)
    Next Index

End Function
```